# Four Layer PCB doubt

Tags: pcb

I was looking a raspberry pi zero board, and I think it is four layer pcb, but I dont understand now why the designer used a ground plane on top and bottom layer?

It is assumed the four layer pcb has  ground and power internal plane, why external plane added, why not only leave the signal plane without ground planes or I can added a polygon plane no connected.

Sorry if I am wrong. I hope somebody can explain in a short answer pls

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of copper pours and only 4 layers on this open Github source design for the Rasp Pi

[image]

You can fork the [design and make your own changes](https://github.com/magkopian/raspberry-pi-compute-module-base-board)

All pours are AC grounds when microvias and low ESR Caps are used.

Comment: Oh gosh whats is a AC ground, where can I learn to do this complex design

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities:

1. It's not a plane. It's ***copper pour*** to fill in areas that have no traces so it's not just blank FR4. Then it's grounded because floating copper can cause noise issues. Less copper to etch saves time and produces less waste chemicals which means faster, cheaper, and more environmentally friendly. Also keeps tension balanced on both sides of the PCB which prevents warping. Don't call it a plane if this is the case because that's wrong.
2. It's more than 4 layers and the outer planes are used as a shield for the inner layers.

The pictures of the PCB I can find show lots of traces on the outer layers so that means #1.

Comment: thanks for your reply very useful for me, really. Now so copper pour grounded is not like ground loop in a two layer PCB routing ground path.. I hope you can understand that I mean

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. But ground loops aren't a concern here, nor are ground loops always a problem. There are often multiple paths for ground if you look hard enough.

Comment: thanks a lot, so ground loop appear when I dont have a ground plane :|

Comment: Ground loops are only a problem when they are big enough to act as an effective loop antenna or have currents circulating around inside the loop itself.

Comment: :|  okay I mean you know a lot of pcb thanks :)

Comment: There's an AC ground plane on each layer because they are needed for controlled impedance tracks.... Vdd is an "AC ground" and critical tracks are angled orthogonal on different layers  FYI @asterix

Comment: (pun). Each layer looks like the ground from an airplane except with runways  (serious) But if a signal is close to large conductor area of the same Voltage   0V= Ground or an "AC ground" , since it is all in one level  we can call  it a ground plane for RF signals or a power plane high DC current or an "AC ground plane"  just like we simplify a Cap at high f is an AC short circuit.

Comment: instead of plane landing on a runway, its a signal runway on the ground plane, but usually planes fly at one level.